# Get a page access token with Facebook graph api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using [angular-facebook](https://github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook) to login users to my app using facebook. Here is the code that logs users in:

```
Facebook.login(function (response) {
  $scope.access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
});
```

and then in order to get the facebook id of the user I send a request like this:

```
Facebook.api('/me', function(response) {
    $scope.user = response;
}
```

Then I save this user in my database.

After this, in `$scope.user.id`, I have let's say ID `abcd`.

Then I use this id to get the page access token by sending a request to the following url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/'+$scope.user.id+'/accounts
```

This is giving me this error:

```
Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation
```

Then, in order to check whether my ID is correct, I manually typed the following url in the browser:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=123123123asdas
```

To my surprise, I get a different ID here, let's say, 'xyz!'

What am I doing wrong? Why did I get different IDs?

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake.

As manage_pages permission should be reviewed first, I was getting the access token with manage_pages permission from graph explorer. As it turned out, using different access_tokens will give you different user IDs. So, I will have to get my app reviewed.

This different ID thing is because of app_scoped IDs Facebook introduced recently.